# How to disable keyguard when activity is alive and renable keyguard when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I don't want my screen to get lock when i am active on particular activity, as soon as activity is destroyed, screen may lock. I tried below thing but it doesn't seems to be working.

```
if (flag){
                 Log.d("Admin", "SCREEN_OFF came from Activity");
                 KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                 KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("abc");
                 lock.disableKeyguard();
            }
```

and while disabling i am using below onDestoroy

```
if (!flag){
        Log.d("Admin", "Reenabling Temp lock onDestroy");
        KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("abc");
        lock.reenableKeyguard();
        }
```

Note : Both are in two different classes. And i am creating two different objects for both is that the reason it is not working. Kindly share your views

You can also share your used code.

Thanks

Comment: add getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); in oncreate

Comment: have you declared the permission in manifest?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you to disable keyguard

```
View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```